# function called for every row in the datagrid although I want to call it only onClick in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, datagrid, material-ui

I got this function:

```
const DataEdit = ({id}) => {
    console.log(id)
}
```

and this column inside my DataGrid(imported from @miu/x-data-grid):
{

```
    field:'Delete',
    headerName:'Delete',
    width:100,
    sortable:false,
    disableClickEventBubbling:true,
    renderCell: (params) => {
        return( 
            <div>
                <IconButton
                aria-label="add an alarm"
                onClick ={DataEdit(params)}
                >
                    <Delete
                    color="error"
                    style={{cursor:'pointer'}}
                    />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
        )
    }
},
```

for some reason the DataEdit function sends console log for every row in the DataGrid in the page, first of all, why is that? second of all, how can I make it work only when I click the IconButton.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace ```onClick ={DataEdit(params)}``` with ```onClick ={() =>DataEdit(params)}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you created it, it is a normal function so it will be loaded in stack and executed as component renders (it will return value to onClick). On the other hand if you rewrite it as:

```
onClick ={() => DataEdit(params)}
```

it will create a function DataEdit and assign it to onClick, thus will be executed only when clicked.